# Change Access server connection from command line

Tags: ms-access, command-line, vbscript, build-automation

I have inherited an Access 2007 ADP application that uses a SQL Server 2008 backend. Is it possible to change the server connection used by the application from the command line or by some VBScript? At the moment, when I am releasing the application to a test/UAT/production environment, I have to open the project, change the server connection, and save it again.

I am trying to automate the build process as much as possible, and currently this is one of the last remaining manual tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, my Google-fu is weak. I just found an article on MSDN which gives the VBA script to achieve this. I modified it to run as a VBScript below:

```
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If (WScript.Arguments.Count = 0) Then
    WScript.Echo "ERROR - the Access project name must be specified"
    WScript.Quit()
End If

Dim sAccessProject
sAccessProject = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments(0))

If (fso.FileExists(sAccessProject) = False) Then
    WScript.Echo "ERROR - the Access project could not be located : " & sAccessProject
    WScript.Quit()
End If

If (WScript.Arguments.Count = 1) Then
    WScript.Echo "ERROR - the SQL Server hostname must be specified"
    WScript.Quit()
End If

Dim sServer
sServer = WScript.Arguments(1)

If (WScript.Arguments.Count = 2) Then
    WScript.Echo "ERROR - the SQL Server database name must be specified"
    WScript.Quit()
End If

Dim sDatabase
sDatabase = WScript.Arguments(2)

Dim sUsername
If (WScript.Arguments.Count = 3) Then
    sUsername = ""
Else
    sUsername = WScript.Arguments(3)
End If

Dim sPassword
If (WScript.Arguments.Count >= 3) Then
    sPassword = ""
Else
    sPassword = WScript.Arguments(4)
End If

ChangeADPConnection sAccessProject, sServer, sDatabase, sUsername, sPassword

Function ChangeADPConnection(strProjectName, strServerName, strDBName, strUN , strPW)

    Dim strConnect

    Dim oApplication
    Set oApplication = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    WScript.Echo "Starting MS Access"
    WScript.Echo "Opening " & strProjectName & " ..."
    oApplication.OpenAccessProject strProjectName
    oApplication.Visible = false

    oApplication.CurrentProject.CloseConnection

    'The Provider, Data Source, and Initial Catalog arguments are required.
    strConnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1" & _
    ";Data Source=" & strServerName & _
    ";Initial Catalog=" & strDBName
    If strUN <> "" Then
        strConnect = strConnect & ";User ID=" & strUN
        If strPW <> "" Then
            strConnect = strConnect & ";Password=" & strPW
        End If
    Else  'Try to use integrated security if no username is supplied.
        strConnect = strConnect & ";Integrated Security=SSPI"
    End If

    WScript.Echo "Setting connection string to " & strConnect

    oApplication.CurrentProject.OpenConnection strConnect
    oApplication.Quit()
    Set oApplication = Nothing

End Function
```

To run it, just use the following from the commandline:

```
cscript connect.vbs Project.adp, "ServerName", "DatabaseName", "Username", "Password"
```

Comment: I love this script works great, however the commas are not needed when running it